# ipad PresentFromBarButtonItem but use UIButton

Tags: ipad, uibutton

The Popover function "PresentFromBarButtonItem" uses a UIBarButtonItem to display the Popover in a nice place relative to the UIBarButton

Is there a way to get the same outcome behavior but with a UIButton? I would imagine there is some more code, but a way to do so relative the button would be very helpful.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do you mean `presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem` instead of `PresentFromBarButtonItem`?

To popup from a UIButton (or any UIView) you can use `presentPopoverFromRect`:

```
//button is some UIButton...
[popoverController presentPopoverFromRect:button.bounds inView:button 
    permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

Comment: If the button is a child of another view, then the relative bounds are not relatively correct. Do I need to compensate for the relative bounds?

Comment: The rect parameter is relative to the the view passed to the inView parameter.  You can create your own CGRect value instead of using button.bounds but it will still be relative to the inView parameter (to the button).

Answer (score 0):

`button.frame` not `button.bounds`

Comment: That's a bit terse for an answer. Care to elaborate?